# Append array to list items (one is to one pairing)

Tags: jquery, html, append, each

My list is currently structured as follows:

```
<ul id="list-items">
  <li class="cat">
    <a href="#">Cat #1</a>
    (2)
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="child-cat">
        <a title="#">Sub cat #1</a>
        (1)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="cat">
    <a href="#">Cat #2</a>
    (2)
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="child-cat">
        <a title="#">Sub cat #2</a>
        (1)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the numbers inside parentheses after the anchor tags. So I did this:

```
jQuery('#list-items li').each(function() {
     b = jQuery(this).first().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).text();
});
```

For my last task, I need to append the above outputs to each of the list item's anchor tags. So I tried this:

```
var b = [];
jQuery('#list-items li').each(function() {
    b = jQuery(this).first().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).text();
});

jQuery('#list-items li a').append(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).append(b[i]);
});
```

That doesn't seem to work. And I don't know why.. Anyone can help me modify my script? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution

```
jQuery('#list-items li > a').append(function() {
    var next = this.nextSibling;
    if(next){
        return $.trim($(next).text())
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/43xgk/)

If you want to create the array `b`, I would recommend `.map()` instead of `.each()`

```
var b = jQuery('#list-items li a').map(function() {
    var next = this.nextSibling;
    if(next){
        return $.trim($(next).text())
    }
});

jQuery('#list-items li a').append(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).append(b[i]);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XWdCH/)

The problem with your code was, inside the first each loop, you were overriding the `b`, instead of adding the value to the array `b`

```
var b = [];
jQuery('#list-items li').each(function() {
    b.push(jQuery(this).first().contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
        }).text());
});

jQuery('#list-items li a').append(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).append($.trim(b[i]));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A2gPk/)

Comment: I will try that out and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: @user2772219n which one did you choose

Comment: I tried it with my solution first. Then chose yours because it's simpler and shorter.